# Generated Minecraft Command Blocks Don't Execute

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I wrote a program that generates command blocks into a minecraft world. The command blocks come in fine, with the correct settings, however they don't execute unless I set the mode of the first block to 'repeating'. I'd rather have them execute once on world load (if a redstone block is in place, as they are in redstone mode).

Is there some way to specify an update or something needs to occur at the position of the redstone block?

Comment: If you didn't answer it yourself, it would have been too broad, because we would need to know the generator program.

Comment: And you can mark your answer as accepted using the checkmark.

Comment: @Fabian Answers mean nothing when voting to close. If you believe the question, by itself, is too broad, then vote to close on that basis alone.

Comment: Ok, but since it's already solved, I don't care much.

Comment: I agree that this is too broad (or "Needs more focus" following the new close vote wording changes), and am flagging it accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whew, found the answer in the file format documentation. A "Tile Tick" is what I need.

The command block needs to be marked as powered, have a redstone block next to it, and have a "tile tick" queued. This Tile Tick needs to be of the type "minecraft:repeating_command_block" (or whatever the ID of the block you need to update is). This will ensure that it will begin repeating once the game loads.

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunk_format#Tile_tick_format